# .inputrc override Control+W

Tags: linux, unix, readline, stty

How do I override Control+W in bash within my .inputrc? The following on its own doesn't work:

```
"\C-w": forward-word
```

It **does** work when I add `stty werase undef` but then the 's' key is mysteriously disabled!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the option `set bind-tty-special-chars Off` in your `.inputrc` file in order to bind `^W` like that. The reason is that:

> Readline, beginning with version 5.0, reads the stty special character
>   settings and binds them to their readline equivalents each time
>   readline() is called [from bug-bash mailing list](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2005-08/msg00003.html)

The `bind-tty-special-chars` option was introduced in 5.1 in order to work around this *feature*. [Readline Changes](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/CHANGES) - search for the option

```
set bind-tty-special-chars Off
"\C-w": forward-word
```

The slightly older-school method involves `.bashrc` like:

```
stty erase undef
bind '"\C-w": forward-word'
```